# "Is to have be" or "Does it have to be"

Tags: grammar

I was writing a sentence:

> Is it have to be written by pen or by pencil?

Now, I presume that, we can write "Does it have to "Is it have to be"

So, which sentence is accurate;

> Is it have to be written by pen or by pencil?

or,

> Does it have to be written by pen or by pencil?

Comment: _Is it have to be...?_ is not idiomatic English.

Comment: What @Kate said, except it's not just "not idiomatic" - it's ***ungrammatical***. Note that it's not particularly idiomatic to say *Is it **required** to be written by pen or by pencil?*, but I'd say at least that one is "syntactically valid". The idiomatic standard for such contexts is to use do-support as in your final example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use *is*, only if the original statement used *is*, like

- *is* is the main verb of the statement: It is hot today. / *Is it hot today?*
- the statement uses the passive voice: The subway is used by students. / *Is the subway used by students?*

Everything else uses *does*.  The statement uses *to have* (It *has* to be written...) so the question uses *does*, not *is*.